# Why would the size of a packed structure be different on Linux and Windows when using gcc?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, mingw, sizeof

In the code below, why is the size of the packed structure different on Linux and Windows when compiled with gcc?

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <cstdio>

// id3 header from an mp3 file
struct header
{    
        uint8_t version[ 2 ];
        uint8_t flags;
        uint32_t size;
} __attribute__((packed));

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
        printf( "%u\n", (unsigned int)sizeof( header ) );
        return 0;
}
```

gcc versions used:

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.2-8ubuntu4) 4.5.2
$ x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ --version
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ (GCC) 4.7.0 20110831 (experimental)
```

Compile and test:

```
$ g++ -Wall packed.cpp -o packed && ./packed
7
$ x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ -Wall packed.cpp -o packed.exe
--> prints '8' when run on Windows.
```

The Linux binary prints the expected size of 7 bytes, the Windows binary 8 bytes. Why the difference?

Comment: My guess is the attribute somehow gets ignored (because of a bug). Use `offsetof(header, size)` to find out if it's so.

Comment: If I compile it directly from windows xp with MinGW g++ 4.5.2, it prints 7. 32 bit though.

Comment: struct sizes varying is expected, which is why it is a good idea to never use/pass structures across compile domains.

Comment: @dwelch: not with packed attribute, thats what its for.

Comment: If it's for an ID3 tag, I suppose the struct packing is part of the format, so no choice there.

Comment: @DrTwox: you're aware you're using an experimental compiler for the second part, right?

Comment: Side note: Any C or C++ code that relies on specific struct member alignment (e.g. reading or writing structures directly to disk or network) smells bad...

Comment: Meh, it only sounds bad.

Comment: @Dani except that it is not universal and universally does not work.  it is just a bad idea.  6502 obviously said it in a better way than I did.  smells, bad, sounds bad, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Section 6.37.3 of the gcc attributes explains it as a difference in ABI specs, see here: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Type-Attributes.html

Comment: The microsoft compiler lets you pack the members as tight as you like. See: #pragma pack for the MS compiler.

Answer (score 7):

`gcc 4.7.0` does it this way to be compatible with 64-bit MSVC++. If you want to pack the structure properly, compile with `-mno-ms-bitfields`. (But then your layout will be incompatible with MSVC++.)

Answer (score 3):

The **attribute**((packed)) is compiler-specific to GCC.
Hence, that code won't even compile with MSVC++. Maybe you used another compiler for Windows, though. However, with MSVC++ you could do this:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <cstdio>

// id3 header from an mp3 file
#pragma pack(push,1)
struct header
{    
        uint8_t version[ 2 ];
        uint8_t flags;
        uint32_t size;
};
#pragma pack(pop)

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
        printf( "%u\n", (unsigned int)sizeof( header ) );
        return 0;
}
```

and the struct will be 7 bytes.

Comment: But it'll compile just fine using mingw under windows, which it appears the OP is using

Answer (score 1):

This is all about **attribute** and **word alignment** in memory

see if you write

```
struct header
{    
        uint8_t version[ 2 ];
        uint8_t flags;
        uint32_t size;
};
```

then linux & windows both have size 8

but when you specify attribute to avoid default world allignment then

```
struct header
{    
        uint8_t version[ 2 ];
        uint8_t flags;
        uint32_t size;
} __attribute__((packed));
```

then in linux because of attritube size becomes 7

**see gcc spec says that**

```
If packed is used on a structure, or if bit-fields are used 
it may be that the Microsoft ABI packs them differently than 
GCC would normally pack them.
```

Comment: Perhaps because the `compiler specific` bit does not matter ? What matters is the quote about ABI.

Comment: i have added that bcz user is going to compile program with attribute((packed)) in windows, attribute((packed)) is not supported in windows compiler

Comment: "windows compiler"? OP specifies he uses GCC both on linux and Windows - MSVC isn't the only compiler around for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Update. Latest MinGW works fine.

Both `g++ (i686-win32-dwarf-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 8.1.0` and
`g++ (x86_64-win32-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 8.1.0`
prints sizeof() of sample code is exactly equal 7 bytes.